# How to format distance units (km, miles) properly depending on country?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Depending on user's locale I would like to format distance units **correctly**. Here are examples of a few countries:

```
UK: 1,540 km
Germany: 1.540 km
France: 1 540 km
Spain: 1540 km
etc.
```

Is there any way I can do this? Some class or library I can use?

Answer (score 2):

```
const km = 1540;

const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", { // Make users locale dynamic
  style: 'unit',
  unit: 'kilometer',
  unitDisplay: 'short',
  maximumFractionDigits: 0
});

console.log(formatter.format(km)); // 1,540 km
```

Answer (score -1):

What language are you using? in .Net the answer will be something like:
`[decimal].ToString("N") + "km"`

see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

In javascript it will be something like:

`new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(number));`

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Comment: This should depend on the user's locale. So if the locale is Germany (de_DE) it should format the distance as above. Personally, I'm using UK.

Comment: I'm asking for Kotlin/Java in Android Studio and not in .NET nor Javascript my friend.

Comment: You can set the users locale with ```CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture  = new CultureInfo("de-DE");``` once on login/start up then all numbers and dates will be localised OR you can use the IFormatProvider interface to set the local on a given Format. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-8.0#system-string-format(system-iformatprovider-system-string-system-object)

Comment: I don't know a great deal of Java - except these days C#/Java are increasingly similar (!?!) so Imagine the solution will be kinda the same. Good luck!